# C# xml serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm serializing an object to xml in c# and I would like to serialize

```
public String Marker { get; set; }
```

into

```
<Marker></Marker>
```

when string Marker has no value.

Now I get

```
<Marker />
```

for `Marker == string.Empty` and no Marker node for `null`.
How can I get this ?

Comment: I think you should expand on why you want to do this. Semantically, the two forms have no difference, so if you are writing a system in which they are not interchangable, it will confuse anyone (including yourself) who looks at it in the future.

Comment: Why would you care whether the element is in short or expanded form? It doesn't change the meaning...

Comment: Is it just that you like the `<Marker></Marker>` representation better or is there a technical reason? It almost never makes a difference (Actually, only the HTML `<script>` tag comes to my mind - and that's due to the deficiency of browsers).

Comment: I know that this doesn't change the meaning, but the parser on servers (old phone central) side only excepts expanded forms.

Comment: Are you only writing XML data or do you also need to consume/read XML? If you only need to read you might be better off using the `XmlWriter` class.

Comment: Only writing needed. I know I could use XmlWriter, but I was just wondering if there's an easier way to do this.

Comment: You will need to write your own serializer to write non standard XML. This will be lots of work, is it necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily suppress the `<Marker>` element if the `Marker` property is null. Just add a `ShouldSerializeMarker()` method:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeMarker()
{
    return Marker != null;
}
```

It will be called automatically by `XmlSerializer` to decide whether or not to include the element in the output.

As for using the expanded form of the `<Marker>` element when the string is empty, there's no easy way to do it (you *could* probably write your own `XmlWriter`, but it would be a pain). But anyway it doesn't make sense, because `<Marker />` and `<Marker></Marker>` have exactly the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the closing tags you have to change the implementation of your xml structure; as far as I understand this topic of serialization separate closing tags are only produced if you are serializing a 'complex' object (eg: a class) and not a 'simple' object (eg: a string).

An example would be:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class ClassToSerialize
{
  private StringWithOpenAndClosingNodeClass mStringWithOpenAndClosingNode;

  [XmlElement]
  public StringWithOpenAndClosingNodeClass Marker
  {
    get { return mStringWithOpenAndClosingNode ?? new StringWithOpenAndClosingNodeClass(); }
    set { mStringWithOpenAndClosingNode = value; }
  }
}

[XmlRoot]
public class StringWithOpenAndClosingNodeClass
{
  private string mValue;

  [XmlText]
  public string Value
  {
    get { return mValue ?? string.Empty; }
    set { mValue = value; }
  }
}
```

If you serialize this object to XML you'll get:

```
<ClassToSerialize><Marker></Marker></ClassToSerialize>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Great idea, but when I serialize `ClassToSerialize` I get `<ClassToSerialize>
  <Marker />
</ClassToSerialize>`. But thanks anyway.

Comment: NO, that's not true because Marker is represented as a separate class (BTW this separate class could be reused for other string properties that need to follow the same pattern)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `IsNullable` property of the [`XMLElementAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) to configure the `XmlSerializer` to generate XML for your `null` value.

Haven't figured out how to produce an opening and closing elements for an element with no value, though. What you have already is perfectly legal XML. That is,

```
<Marker></Marker>
```

is the same as

```
<Marker/>
```

Do you *really* need both opening and closing tags?

Comment: Unfortunately yes... Parser on servers side only excepts expanded forms. Shorter form returns an error, but when I manually send expanded form it works like a charm.

Comment: So the solution after you write the file to replace all the shorter forms with the expanded forms by looping through the file.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll call it my emergency plan if no faster solution appears.

Comment: @Jonah Did you need to resort to your emergency plan?